# make and cmake. installation not recognized

Tags: powershell, cmake, environment-variables, rna-seq, genomics

I am currently trying to install kallisto locally on a Windows machine using the following installation process:https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/manual

To install kallisto I need functioning cmake and make commands. I am currently on a PC so, I installed chocolatey, cmake and make. After installing cmake, I went into Control Panel > System & Security > System > (In search bar going to: "View Advanced System Settings" > Environment Variables... and set PATH to the location of where I installed cmake. The plan was also to do this with make once I knew it was working.

https://chmi-sops.github.io/mydoc_kallisto.html#build-an-index-from-reference-transcriptome-fasta-file

More specifically This link above has more explicit instructions for what I did. I used the "Installing Kallisto on a Windows OS" to install cmake to make it accessible when I try to run it. I followed all the instructions up to Step 6, subbullet2.  The option to do "PATH -> Edit -> New Note" Doesn't exist for me, and instead I get a popup window called "Edit System Variable" where I can type in the Variable name and the Variable Value. I figure that is fine, but something to note. So, into the Variable Value, I inputted the location of my cmake program. (IE C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ )

However, when I return to powershell,

in the following pwd (C:\Users\MyName\bin)

and enter

```
cmake ..
```

I get the following error message.

```
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   ".."


CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/MyName" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
PS C:\Users\MyName\bin> cmake ..
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   ".."

CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/MyName" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I also tried to run

```
 choco cmake ..
```

(to see if maybe I needed to call on chocolatey to get it to work?)

and got

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd Program Files
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I considered the possibility that I needed to have the cmake directory as my pwd to get it to run, so I tried to change my pwd to (IE `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\` ), but I get the following error message when trying to change my pwd to Program Files (even though I know for sure it is contained in C:

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd Program Files
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ultimately, I am trying to calculate TPM values from single-cell RNAseq libraries. The way I am hoping to do that (Through advice from a forum) is to run kallisto and get the output transcript/gene length matrix do be inputted into the calculation for translating count values to TPM values.If you're familiar please comment on this approach and whether or not I'm even on the right track.

I tried to change the System PATH to the location of cmake, and expected `cmake ..` to run, but it did not.

Comment: The last parameter to `cmake` should refer to the **directory** with where a CMake project resides. You run `cmake ..` from the directory `C:\Users\MyName\bin`, so the last parameter refers to the directory `C:\Users\MyName`. But there is no CMake project in that directory (no `CMakeLists.txt` file in it). This is what CMake tells you.

Comment: Additionally, you need to quote string arguments with spaces in PowerShell: `cd "Program Files"`

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev . I am confused about the System PATH compared to the regular path/pwd. So, I have the path to the CMakeLists.txt In my System PATH. However, if I'm trying to run kallisto, there is a whole other file path that I would use to run that--currently Users\MyName\kallisto\ . Should I be trying to install CMake somewhere into the Users\MyName\kallisto\ file path? I'm having trouble understanding how the two file paths are supposed to relate to each other. When should each filepath be used as my pwd?

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen . Quotes weren't necessary for single-word file names, so the need for them didn't occur to me with the two-word filename. This was a massive help to me.

Comment: Yw! You might want to read [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)